# Removing blanks in Python

Tags: python, csv, mapreduce, blank-line

I am new to Python so i am trying to make is simple as possible. I am working with CSV file that contains data that i have to Mapreduce. In my mapper portion I get blank data which does not let me Reduce is. This is due to CSV file has blanks in it. I need an advice on how to remove blanks in my Mapper so it will not go into my Reducer.

```
Example of my result.
BLUE 1
GY  1
WT  1
    1
WH  1
    1
BLACK   1
    1
GN  1
BLK 1
BLACK   1
RED 1
```

My code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from operator import itemgetter
import sys

sys_stdin = open("Parking_Violations.csv", "r")

for line in sys_stdin:
    line = line.split(",")
    vehiclecolor = line[33]          #This is the column in CSV file where data i need is located.

    try:                                                     
        issuecolor = str(vehiclecolor)
        print("%s\t%s" % (issuecolor, 1))

     except ValueError:
        continue
```

Comment: Try to use [str.strip() function](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) let me know if this works :)

Comment: I have no idea what this is supposed to do. Why `line[33]`? What's at that index? Why do you import `typing` and `itemgetter` and not use them?

Comment: @FelipeBorges works to fix what, exactly?

Comment: No, it doesn't, because I can't see what's at that index. You also say "blacks" instead of "blanks", multiple times.

Comment: hint: "multiple" implies more than one. You've left another typo in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the builtin [string.strip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) function

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from operator import itemgetter
import sys
from typing import List, Any

sys_stdin = open("Parking_Violations.csv", "r")

for line in sys_stdin:
    vehiclecolor = line[33].strip()

    if vehiclecolor:
        issuecolor = str(vehiclecolor)
        print("%s\t%s" % (issuecolor, 1))
```

What it does is getting the 33rd line and strips all whitespaces from it `.strip()`. This assumes that your file has actually 33 lines in it otherwise it will raise an exception.

Then it checks if the vehiclecolor has any characters via the `if` and prints it only if there is a value.

In Python an expression of an empty string is recognized as "false".

Comment: vehiclecolor = line[33] this is the column in CSV file that has vehicle colors.

Comment: In my CSV file line 33 looks like this
GRY
GY
BLK
BLK

GY
BK
GY
GY
ORANG
WH
BK
WH
GR
BK
BK
GY
BLK
RD
ORANG

GRAY
WH